# How we apply click on an icon in ag-grid (angular 8)?

Tags: angular8, ag-grid

I have 3 icons in a cell. I want to made a function on clicking an icon in 3rd icon.  I am trying to made a call to deleteTrainee() function with "console.log("abc") as its definition part" . But it does not display "abc". Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'ALL CATEGORY', field: 'name',cellRenderer: function(params){
      let cellValue = ''; 
      cellValue = `<a href ="category/categoryDetail/${params.data}">${ params.data.name}</a>`;
      return cellValue;
    },
    },
    {headerName: 'DESCRIPTION', field: 'id',resizable: true },
    {headerName: 'WEBINAR', field: 'username', cellRenderer: function(params){
      let cellValue = ''; 
      cellValue = '<a href ="category/categoryDetail">' + params.value + '</a>';
      return cellValue;
    } },
    {headerName: 'DATE',field:'website'},
    {headerName: 'ACTION', field: '', cellRenderer: (data) => {
       return `<a href="trainee/editTrainee" class="icon-grid"><img class="icon-mark" src="../../assets/img/icon/edit.svg"/></a><a class="icon-grid"><img class="icon-mark" src="../../assets/img/icon/rotate-cw.svg" /></a><span class="icon-grid" (click)="deleteTrainee(params.data.id)"><img class="icon-mark" src="../../assets/img/icon/trash-2.svg" /></span>`;
    },
  }
  ];
```

Comment: If you cell is complex and reusable, you could use cellRendererFramework.

Comment: can you create a working stackblitz or plunkr for this?